# minimal_cocoa in wxWidgets - What should it look like at run - Post screenshot here please

Tags: c++, macos, user-interface, wxwidgets

Hello wxWidgets/C++ Devs:
    I am new to both XCode and wxWidgets I want to know what minimal_cocoa should should look like? I am using the latest wxWidgets as of yesterday. I did a git clone / recurse submodules.

Since I am new I am going through some documentation here:
https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Creating_Xcode_projects_for_wxWidgets_applications.

My question is what should Run of minimal_cocoa look like? My minimal_cocoa does not run. pressing 'run' in xcode returns immediately nothing happens.

My environment is

- OSX 10.15.4
- XCODE 11.4.1

**Here are the stated content goals:**

```
Contents
1   Create the library
2   Compile the basic sample.app
3   In Build Settings
4   Finally
```

I have successfully  performed 1) and 2), however When I press run of 2) nothing happens.
I have set the XCODE Breakpoints and they are never reached. This should be running correct ?

Could one of you wxWidgets folks please put a screenshot up of their result of compiling and running minimal_cocoa?

Here is the minimal.cpp provided with wxWidgets

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Name:        minimal.cpp
// Purpose:     Minimal wxWidgets sample
// Author:      Julian Smart
// Modified by:
// Created:     04/01/98
// Copyright:   (c) Julian Smart
// Licence:     wxWindows licence
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// ============================================================================
// declarations
// ============================================================================

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// headers
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// For compilers that support precompilation, includes "wx/wx.h".
#include "wx/wxprec.h"

#ifdef __BORLANDC__
    #pragma hdrstop
#endif

// for all others, include the necessary headers (this file is usually all you
// need because it includes almost all "standard" wxWidgets headers)
#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include "wx/wx.h"
#endif

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// resources
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// the application icon (under Windows it is in resources and even
// though we could still include the XPM here it would be unused)
#ifndef wxHAS_IMAGES_IN_RESOURCES
    #include "../sample.xpm"
#endif

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// private classes
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// Define a new application type, each program should derive a class from wxApp
class MyApp : public wxApp
{
public:
    // override base class virtuals
    // ----------------------------

    // this one is called on application startup and is a good place for the app
    // initialization (doing it here and not in the ctor allows to have an error
    // return: if OnInit() returns false, the application terminates)
    virtual bool OnInit() wxOVERRIDE;
};

// Define a new frame type: this is going to be our main frame
class MyFrame : public wxFrame
{
public:
    // ctor(s)
    MyFrame(const wxString& title);

    // event handlers (these functions should _not_ be virtual)
    void OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& event);
    void OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& event);

private:
    // any class wishing to process wxWidgets events must use this macro
    wxDECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// constants
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// IDs for the controls and the menu commands
enum
{
    // menu items
    Minimal_Quit = wxID_EXIT,

    // it is important for the id corresponding to the "About" command to have
    // this standard value as otherwise it won't be handled properly under Mac
    // (where it is special and put into the "Apple" menu)
    Minimal_About = wxID_ABOUT
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// event tables and other macros for wxWidgets
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// the event tables connect the wxWidgets events with the functions (event
// handlers) which process them. It can be also done at run-time, but for the
// simple menu events like this the static method is much simpler.
wxBEGIN_EVENT_TABLE(MyFrame, wxFrame)
    EVT_MENU(Minimal_Quit,  MyFrame::OnQuit)
    EVT_MENU(Minimal_About, MyFrame::OnAbout)
wxEND_EVENT_TABLE()

// Create a new application object: this macro will allow wxWidgets to create
// the application object during program execution (it's better than using a
// static object for many reasons) and also implements the accessor function
// wxGetApp() which will return the reference of the right type (i.e. MyApp and
// not wxApp)
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);

// ============================================================================
// implementation
// ============================================================================

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// the application class
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// 'Main program' equivalent: the program execution "starts" here
bool MyApp::OnInit()
{
    // call the base class initialization method, currently it only parses a
    // few common command-line options but it could be do more in the future
    if ( !wxApp::OnInit() )
        return false;

    // create the main application window
    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame("Minimal wxWidgets App");

    // and show it (the frames, unlike simple controls, are not shown when
    // created initially)
    frame->Show(true);

    // success: wxApp::OnRun() will be called which will enter the main message
    // loop and the application will run. If we returned false here, the
    // application would exit immediately.
    return true;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// main frame
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

// frame constructor
MyFrame::MyFrame(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title)
{
    // set the frame icon
    SetIcon(wxICON(sample));

#if wxUSE_MENUS
    // create a menu bar
    wxMenu *fileMenu = new wxMenu;

    // the "About" item should be in the help menu
    wxMenu *helpMenu = new wxMenu;
    helpMenu->Append(Minimal_About, "&About\tF1", "Show about dialog");

    fileMenu->Append(Minimal_Quit, "E&xit\tAlt-X", "Quit this program");

    // now append the freshly created menu to the menu bar...
    wxMenuBar *menuBar = new wxMenuBar();
    menuBar->Append(fileMenu, "&File");
    menuBar->Append(helpMenu, "&Help");

    // ... and attach this menu bar to the frame
    SetMenuBar(menuBar);
#else // !wxUSE_MENUS
    // If menus are not available add a button to access the about box
    wxSizer* sizer = new wxBoxSizer(wxHORIZONTAL);
    wxButton* aboutBtn = new wxButton(this, wxID_ANY, "About...");
    aboutBtn->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &MyFrame::OnAbout, this);
    sizer->Add(aboutBtn, wxSizerFlags().Center());
    SetSizer(sizer);
#endif // wxUSE_MENUS/!wxUSE_MENUS

#if wxUSE_STATUSBAR
    // create a status bar just for fun (by default with 1 pane only)
    CreateStatusBar(2);
    SetStatusText("Welcome to wxWidgets!");
#endif // wxUSE_STATUSBAR
}


// event handlers

void MyFrame::OnQuit(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    // true is to force the frame to close
    Close(true);
}

void MyFrame::OnAbout(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event))
{
    wxMessageBox(wxString::Format
                 (
                    "Welcome to %s!\n"
                    "\n"
                    "This is the minimal wxWidgets sample\n"
                    "running under %s.",
                    wxVERSION_STRING,
                    wxGetOsDescription()
                 ),
                 "About wxWidgets minimal sample",
                 wxOK | wxICON_INFORMATION,
                 this);
}
```

Comment: did you build the library itself? You should build the library first and then try to buiold and run the samples.

Comment: yes I did successfully build lib - i said so in question - "I have successfully performed 1) and 2)". Could you please send me your screenshot from your running minimal_cocoa app?

Comment: can you try to build the sample from the Terminal?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the XCODE command line tools - what are the steps for building this from command line?  Would you please send me a screenshot of your build of minimal_cocoa - And yes Library is building and minimal-cocoa is building.